# How can I keep track of a variable in android app?

Tags: javascript, java, android, variables, android-activity

when user enter to the app he chose team 1 (Brazil)or team 2(Argentine) after that he chose yellow or red card then he chose a player after that in the first page it will show the player number and color of card.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wv1Ky.png)

***My Question is How can keep track of the number of card and instead of showing player number I show how many either yellow or red card does team have .***

**CardActivity**

```
public class CardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_card);
}

private void setCardData(int card) {
    SharedPreferences settings getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MainThisApp", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putInt("card", card);
    editor.apply();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Myapp.game.NumberActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void setRedCard(View view) {

    ((Variable) this.getApplication()).setSomeVariable("card_yellow");

    setCardData(0);
}

public void setYellowCard(View view) {

    ((Variable) this.getApplication()).setSomeVariable("card_red");

    setCardData(1);
}}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MainThisApp", 0);
    int check = prefs.getInt("check", 0);

    String s = ((Variable) this.getApplication()).getSomeVariable();
    try{
        Integer number = Integer.valueOf(s);
        System.out.println(number);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (check == 50) {
        TextView view = null;
        int country = prefs.getInt("country", -1);
        int card = prefs.getInt("card", -1);

        if (country == 0 & card == 0) {

            view = findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        }
        if (country == 0 & card == 1) {

            view = findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        }
        if (country == 1 & card == 0) {

            view = findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        }
        if (country == 1 & card == 1) {

            view = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        }
        view.setText(String.valueOf(prefs.getInt("number",1)));
    }

}

public void chooseBrasil(View view) {
    setCountryData(0);
}

private void setCountryData(int country) {
    SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MainThisApp", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putInt("country", country);
    editor.apply();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, CardActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
public void chooseArgentine(View view) {
    setCountryData(1);
}
```

**NumberActivity**

```
public class NumberActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_number);
    }

private void setNumberData(int number) {
    SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MainThisApp", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putInt("number", number);
    editor.putInt("check", 50);
    editor.apply();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void setNumber1(View view) {
    setNumberData(1);
}

public void setNumber2(View view) {
    setNumberData(2);
}

public void setNumber3(View view) {
    setNumberData(3);
}

public void setNumber4(View view) {
    setNumberData(4);
}

public void setNumber5(View view) {
    setNumberData(5);
}

public void setNumber6(View view) {
    setNumberData(6);
}

public void setNumber7(View view) {
    setNumberData(7);
}

public void setNumber8(View view) {
    setNumberData(8);
}
```

Comment: You can either save the number of yellow/red cards in shared preferences or use a different storage capability (SQLite/external file). That is if you want it saved between sessions. If not, then you can create a class which will hold the state of these cards and other relevant logic.

Comment: can you show me the way of converting  shared preferences  data to string ?

Comment: You can check out the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor#putString(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).

Comment: I did it and it works but the problem is the value is not showing all of them it only show one

Comment: Then you need to save a list of cards. Go over the documentation again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ROOM](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room) database or [Shared preferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences).

Or just use object in kotlin (Singelton) to save any data in Object that you can get and set everywhere